# Can we send notification using QuickBlox as a new user joined/added to a private Group without using APNS?

Tags: ios, quickblox

i am integrating an iPhone App integrating it with `QuickBlox` my question is , can we send notifications to users that were added to a private group using `QuickBlox`?
PS - i am not using APNS just dealing with local notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be possible to get "all the dialogs from Quickblox" which are initiated with your Quickblox ids.

now after getting all the dialogs - you need to identify which are new/unread messages and based on that you may able to generate the local notification for each new dialog.

below is the code to get all the dialogs from Quickblox service.

/**
 Retrieve chat dialogs for page

```
@param page Page with skip and limit
 @param extendedRequest Set of request parameters
 @param successBlock Block with response instance, arrays of chat dialogs and chat dialogs users IDs and page instance if request succeded
 @param errorBlock Block with response instance if request failed

 @return An instance of QBRequest for cancel operation mainly.
 */
+ (QB_NONNULL QBRequest *)dialogsForPage:(QB_NULLABLE QBResponsePage *)page
                         extendedRequest:(QB_NULLABLE NSDictionary QB_GENERIC(NSString *, NSString *) *)extendedRequest
                            successBlock:(QB_NULLABLE void(^)(QBResponse * QB_NONNULL_S response, NSArray QB_GENERIC(QBChatDialog *) * QB_NULLABLE_S dialogObjects,NSSet QB_GENERIC(NSNumber *) * QB_NULLABLE_S dialogsUsersIDs, QBResponsePage * QB_NULLABLE_S page))successBlock
                              errorBlock:(QB_NULLABLE QBRequestErrorBlock)errorBlock;
```

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Comment: thanks Akash, that will works fine but also i just found a solution for my problem that works without APNS too and it is also recommended by the QB for sending notification for group members as they joined

steps-
preparing message and sends it to the user with 

` [[QBChat instance] sendSystemMessage:inviteMessage completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
 }];`

and receiving this notification in delegate

`- (void)chatDidReceiveSystemMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message
{
}`

[Source](https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Guide:_Getting_Started_with_Chat_API)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can send the push notifications to all individual person who are under the private chat.

You just need to enable the push notification option from quickblox developer portal.

Do login under your quickblox a/c and on the side menu, you will see "Push notifications" option.

https://admin.quickblox.com/signin

Under that section, you will see "Channels" option - choose those platform which you want to send notifications.

The last thing, on same section there will be one option named "Settings" - under which you have to upload your certificates to send the notification.

In a case of iOS - You have to upload "Apple Push Notification Service (APNS)" for Development / Deployment based on your requirement.

After successfully upload of APNS certificate it will validate and show the status as "Activate" it the certificate will be proper.

Now your application is eligible to send/receive notification.

Review below link for further understanding in detail.

https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-messages_users-ios

Comment: actually i'm not using APNS here, i'm working with local notifications so is there any chances for this?

Comment: okay, in that case, if your application will be in foreground than you will be able to get the message from Quickblox service when a new message will come - you may able to generate the new local notification based on that details from QBDialog.

Comment: exactly! but the problem is how would i know a person just added me to the group? i mean i don't know the appropriate delegate for this? please help about this.

Comment: I have given new answer on same thread - pl review it for further details!